# Socket.io with node.js slow with multiple users

Tags: php, node.js, sockets

I have a site built with PHP that was using ratchet for the sockets, which worked okay, but once I had lots (100+) connections, it starts having issues (crashing).  It seems like ratchet was not the way to go.

I have redesigned to use socket.io with node.js but still keeping apache to serve the php.  It works fine with only a few users, but 20+ the response time is horrible.  When the users make a hit to website (to pages that uses sockets) at around same time, they get a horribly delayed response (5+ seconds).  Its hard for me to test (how?).  The json sent back is minimum 1 field or 2. 
The development website currently is placeadvocacy.org

Sorry if this is confusing - Im a teacher playing around w/ this stuff. I can try to elaborate.
Thanks, Im really at a loss,
JB

Comment: Is your socket.io server behind apache?

Comment: If I understand correctly, yes, apache is serving main site, and node.js is just for websockets.