# Mysql slow with multiple queries at same time

Tags: php, mysql, node.js

I have a large mysql table (1 million rows) that if my users hit at the same time will make lots of queries at around the same time (say 300 queries over span of 5 seconds), and it brings my site to a halt (takes like 22 seconds to execute all of the queries).

Is this normal, what can I do?

I tried with smaller table, and it works fine, but on larger table its brutal.

Any ideas?

I tried on both php and node and its not that, its my db.
Thanks

This is what EXPLAIN on the table says:
Current selection does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available.
Field   Type    Null    Key Default Extra
id      int(11) NO  PRI NULL    auto_increment
game_id int(11) NO      NULL
user_id int(11) NO      NULL
question_id varchar(10) NO
answer  text    YES     NULL
distanceAway    int(11) YES     NULL
points  int(11) YES     NULL
questionNum int(11) NO      NULL
lat float   YES     NULL
longg   float   YES     NULL
color   varchar(6)  NO      NULL
submitTime  timestamp   NO      CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
avg float   NO      NULL

Comment: is the db properly indexed? also depends on how you're querying.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46853339/socket-io-with-node-js-slow-with-multiple-users is that related to your previous post by any chance?

Comment: Have you considered using  a query level cache ? 
Please refer https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache.html

Comment: Can you show us the query? A select * from article would be deadly of course

Comment: Without more information, there's not much concrete advice to give. But tuning a query is a bit if an art, and there are tools to help you. [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html) can help you identify places indexes can be improved. [Optimizing SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-optimization.html) has enough information to make your head explode, but your answer is in there.

Comment: It has a simple int unique id. Different queries all slow down system, anything querying that large db.  like count(id)

Comment: Query example: SELECT COUNT(id) as total FROM answers

Comment: Yes, it is related to previous post.  I thought maybe the issue was I was using php/ratchet for sockets.  So I rewrote the whole thing in javascript/node.js.  But the issue lingers, and I did some tests (like running the same select count(id).  If I run it just once, it is quick (fully back in 600ms), but running 10 of them consequetively, slows down considerable (6 seconds).  Im pooling connections (Ive played with sizes (10-100), nothing helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a PK column and index all the columns where parameters are passing in queries. Index with unique or normal as applicable.

Comment: Durgesh, thanks so much, that did it (mostly, still not as fast as I want, but 90% faster), awesome.  I had a primary key, I didnt realize importance of indexing other columns.  Thank you!